# How to generate Payment Token in GooglePay & ApplePay for Authorize.net (In Mobile App Transaction)?

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, authorize.net, applepay, google-pay

[image: This is the Above API to process the payment through google pay also ApplePay]

This is the Above API to process the payment through google pay also ApplePay. Under OpaqueValues the datavalue is base64 token. My Question is how to generate this token from googlePay and ApplePay so that we can process the payment in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Browsing Authorize.Net's documentation, I came across the following: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/in-app.html#Google_Pay%E2%84%A2

> #### Using the Payment Network Token
>
> After obtaining a payment network token from Google Pay, encode the token's blob using Base64:
>
> ```
> new String(Base64.encode(paymentData.getPaymentMethodToken().getToken().getBytes()))
> ```
>
> Submit a `createTransactionRequest` API call. Set the `dataDescriptor` field to `COMMON.GOOGLE.INAPP.PAYMENT`, and set the `dataValue` field to the Base64-encoded blob.

Comment: yes i also read this but i dnt know from where this paymentData.getPaymentMethodToken method comes and where to send after so that we get token ??

Comment: If you are using the [Pay Flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/pay), it comes from [`onPaymentResult` callback](https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/blob/ad1bd7252659f4c07598d69cc2aa683f424c5d36/pay/lib/src/widgets/pay_button.dart#L77)

Comment: More generally speaking, that payment token is from the Google Pay response to the `loadPaymentData` from within your Google Pay code. Here's a video tutorial: https://youtu.be/kH0nafGhbww?t=1355